# Tutorial to explain Struts 2, Spring, and Hibernate integration

Tags: hibernate, spring, struts2

For work I've been asked to create a web application that will be fairly basic. A front end gui on top of a database that stores data entered in through forms. My problem is that I'm not a web developer, more a back end developer, so I don't have much experience with Struts or anything else. So I've been doing a lot of research and I guess I'm going to just create a generic Struts 2 app using Hibernate. It also seems like Hibernate is made easy when using Spring.

Anyway, my problem is that I learn best through example and try as I might I haven't found a really good tutorial or example of a basic Struts app that makes use of Spring and Hibernate. I've read just about all of them out there I can find and so far they all seem to leave something out, or just assume I know something that I don't, or they're too outdated. So I guess I'm asking if someone can perhaps point me to an example app that creates a full Struts, Spring, and Hibernate app.I've read the tutorials on the Struts websites, and attempted to get through the documentation on the Spring and Hibernate sites but I just need something that walks me through an example with some decent explanations from beginning to end. If anyone has some thoughts please let me know. Thank you.

And I did search through here and read a number of suggestions I've found but still nothing that I'm looking for.

Comment: If you're already going with Spring, I'd recommend using Spring MVC instead of Struts. I've found it very easy to use for simple cases, and very flexible for more complex things.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions but again, a tutorial or something where I could read up on it and see a well explained example would be ideal. Thanks.

Comment: That sounds very helpful, thank you. I've most recently been trying to use this [link](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/struts-2-spring-2-jpa-ajax.html) but again I'm getting nothing but errors trying to run the project. I'm assuming it's because the tutorial is outdated, and this is the Struts 2 site. Very frustrating.

Comment: @cardician That *is* an outdated tutorial, but without knowing what kinds of errors you're getting, or why, it's also impossible to see if it's easy to correct either your project, or the tutorial.

Comment: Granted, but really that's not the point of my question. I'm encountering issues like I do with that tutorial no matter where I look. Everything regarding Struts 2, Spring, and Hibernate seems to be outdated. Even their own sites don't seem to have updated tutorials for their own products. So I'm just asking if someone knows of any tutorials that might be kept up to date and provide a complete example.

Comment: **[Struts 2 + Spring + Hibernate integration example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-hibernate-integration-example/)**

Comment: @cardician It'll never be corrected if you don't say what's wrong with it, file a JIRA ticket against it, etc. Open source projects rely on people providing actual information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I guess I'm asking if someone can perhaps point me to an example
>   app that creates a full Struts, Spring, and Hibernate app.

You can try to use [AppFuse 2](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) to generate a web application using Struts 2 , Hibernate and Spring . It contains a simple web form that creates an user account and save it to the DB. Here is the [demo](http://demo.appfuse.org/appfuse-struts) site for the generated web application .Use **admin/admin** to login as an administrator , **user/user** to login as a normal user.

You should probably have to know [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) too as AppFuse 2 uses it to generate the source code for the web application and the generated application uses it as the build tool.

Comment: I've looked into AppFuse. The idea is nice but the site is a mess. Too many lacking directions, things that don't build as they're supposed to, and other issues I've encountered while playing with it. I just want a site that will show a fully fleshed out and detailed explanation on how to do each step. So far I've not found a single one that doesn't leave something out.

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/struts-2-tutorials/ for struts 2 tutorials and this url http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-hibernate-integration-example/ which I think is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like dimensions of [this tutorial](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2013/08/struts-2-hibernate-3-integration.html#.UvKO4NbpF4M).